# What happens after someone receives Ubuntu membership?

Tags: community, ubuntu-membership

What happens after someone receive Ubuntu membership?

How s/he receives the benefits listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership#Benefits_of_Membership)? I knew it's documented somewhere on the wiki but so far couldn't find any trace of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is essentially what happens.

Most people appear at the regional membership boards on IRC.

After you appear at the membership board, in the IRC session, they will ask you some questions related to your membership - [logs of the IRC session I was at are here](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/10/21/%23ubuntu-meeting.html).

After that, what happens is something like this:

- Someone adds you to the Ubuntu members group on Launchpad.
- Sometime in the next 48 hours, a cronjob adds a @ubuntu.com email alias for you.
- At that point, you can apply for the other benefits of membership such as a IRC cloak, add your blog to the Ubuntu Planet etc.

Answer (score 1):

Which benefit do you want / need ? Some occur once the approving board takes action, can take a week or so (ubuntu email), some you need to configure yourself.

For an irc cloak, for example, ask on #ubuntu

For acknowledgement on the forums, post in the RC or ask a forums admin.

The page you posted has links to various pages for other benefits (business cards, syndication on the planet, etc).

Comment: Thanks, I was asking about all :-) and you answer helped a lot, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I got membership 10 days now and I got no notification about the ubuntu email, do you know where should I check to see if someone ran that script and something went wrong with mine, or they just didn't run it yet?

Comment: Send yourself an email @ you@ubuntu.com

Comment: it worked after asking my friend to send me an email to the @ ubuntu one, Thanks You :)